# Appcompatx, os Bundle at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)

Tags: android, bundle, android-appcompat

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ImageView imageView;
    public Animation animation;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    public ConstraintLayout layout;

    private static final int SPLASH_DURATION = 2500;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        layout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.splashLayout);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_splash1);
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.rotate);


    }

    private  void initFunctionality (){
        layout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.startAnimation(animation);
                animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeNewActivity(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class, true);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
            }
        },SPLASH_DURATION);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        initFunctionality();
    }
}
```

erooor

```
   W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
   W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 


 androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
I/art:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void artem.shevchuk.myapplication.activity.SplashActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SplashActivity.java:29)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/artem.shevchuk.myapplication-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/artem.shevchuk.myapplication-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void artem.shevchuk.myapplication.activity.SplashActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SplashActivity.java:29)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xacdba0c0, tid 9085
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x93f12300, tid 9119
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa5c06620: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5c06620: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa5c034f0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5c06620: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa5c034f0)
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, data=22KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=22KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=57KB
    After code cache collection, code=53KB, data=53KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5c06620: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa5c034f0)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

its layout file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.SplashActivity"
android:id="@+id/splashLayout">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv_splash1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvAppname"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
android:text="@string/app_name"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_splash1" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvDescritpion"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
android:text="@string/opis"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAppname" />

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDescritpion" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

I don't know how to fix it. its my layout.thx man who redact my post.
I need your help. I saw many different forums. My application on the emulator comes off only the first page it loads and then knocks out.
That is, the launch seems to be there but after it the home screen of the phone and the error is all.
OsX mac. EMULATOR Nexus 5 api 24

SKD

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'



implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.2.0'
implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.8@aar") {
    transitive = true
}

}
```

Activity Utilities

```
public class ActivityUtilities {

public static ActivityUtilities activityUtilities = null;

public static ActivityUtilities getInstance() {
    if (activityUtilities == null) {
        activityUtilities = new ActivityUtilities();
    }
    return activityUtilities;

}

public void invokeNewActivity(Activity activity, Class<?> tClass, boolean shoulgFinish) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, tClass);
    if (shoulgFinish) {
        activity.finish();
    }
}

public void invokeCustomUrlActivity(Activity activity, Class<?> tClass, String pageTitle, String pageUrl, boolean shouldFinish) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, tClass);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstans.BUNDLE_KEY_TITLE, pageTitle);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstans.BUNDLE_KEY_URL, pageUrl);
    if (shouldFinish) {
        activity.finish();
    }
}

public void invokeCommonQuizActivity(Activity activity, Class<?> tClass, String categoryId, boolean shouldFinish) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, tClass);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstans.BUNDLE_KEY_INDEX, categoryId);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    if (shouldFinish) {
        activity.finish();
    }
}

public void invokeScoreCardActivity(Activity activity, Class<?> tClass, int questionsCount, int score, int wrongAns, int skip, String categoryId, ArrayList<ResultModel> resultList, boolean shouldFinish) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, tClass);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstans.BUNDLE_KEY_SCORE, score);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstans.QUESTIONS_IN_TEST, questionsCount);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstans.BUNDLE_KEY_WRONG_ANS, wrongAns);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstans.BUNDLE_KEY_SKIP, skip);
    intent.putExtra(Appconstans.BUNDLE_KEY_INDEX, categoryId);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Appconstans.BUNDLE_KEY_ITEM, resultList);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    if (shouldFinish) {
        activity.finish();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can u show import statements and layout code ? I think this caused due to mismatch in  imports (in activity) and views (in layout).

Comment: i add layout files

Comment: Need more information such as minimum sdk, sdk of emulator you ran,  ActivityUtilities class.

Comment: I checked your code by commenting the line "ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeNewA..." , on a device running on Nougat. It worked perfectly.

Comment: I add all info.

Comment: Might be that `in app billing library` dependency or the `material drawer aar` uses the old support files and you are getting conflicts? Remove them one at a time and see. Also I expected more repo's that just jitpack for androidx resolution? add `google()` under `repositories {`'

Comment: Does it actually crash? There are loads of these "errors" because of the way the support library is implemented (it's working in a safe way with platform code that is only present in new versions of Android).